# How to pass variable length structure to pinvoke C function in C#

Tags: pinvoke

My `C structure` format is this:

```
typedef struct pt_data {
  int Length;   ///< Length of the Data field in bytes
  uchar Data[1];    ///< The data itself, variable length
} PT_DATA;
```

My `C function` is this:

```
PT_STATUS PTSetFingerData (
IN PT_CONNECTION hConnection,
IN PT_LONG lSlotNr,
IN PT_DATA *pFingerData
)
```

Now I  want to put a wrapper for this function in `C#`.

How can I do this? In particular, how can I do this for passing the `C# PT_DATA struct` to `PT_DATA C struct`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to marshal the data manually. A variable length struct cannot be marshalled by the p/invoke marshaller.

In your case the obvious way to do this would be to declare the `PTDATA*` argument as `byte[]` in your p/invoke. Then you just need to populated the byte array before calling the function. The first 4 bytes are the length of the subsequent data.

```
static byte[] GetPTData(byte[] arr)
{
    byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(arr.Length);
    byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(int) + arr.Length];
    Array.Copy(len, data, sizeof(int));
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, data, sizeof(int), arr.Length);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: [DllImport("tfm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static int PTSetFingerData(
            int ahConnection,
            int alSlotNr,
            ref byte[] apFingerData);  Is this correct Pinvoke?  Can u give me more explanation ! Thank u very much.

Comment: No that is not correct. Do it exactly as I said. I said `byte[]`. That is already a reference. You can never use `ref` with a managed type. Update: I see our comments crossed. I guess you already realised that the `ref` was wrong.

Comment: i have one more questions to ask. i have posted as a question.. can u answer that if u r knew!

Comment: Hi David Heffernan, I have posted my question kindly please answer if u know.